# Is there an issue in Java ListView?

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I'm having an anomaly with java ListView cell factory. I have an *if* statement that just evaluate if a cell item is equal to other, if it is, then I just change the text color of the cell. But for a weird reason, after I add a new element to the ListView, other(s) cell(s) or item(s) meet the condition so the result is many cells with a changed color against my will.

I'm using JFXListView a custom ListView from the [JFoenix](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix) Material Design Library.
Also I had the same problem before, but changing the disable property value, when I scrolled the listview, the same anomaly happened! One cell that wasn't disable, was disable after scroll (the item was hidden on scroll and when it stopped being hidden, the anomaly became manifest (The cell became being disabled against my will).

```
zoneListView.setCellFactory(listSelectionView ->
        {
            ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
                @Override
                public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if (empty) {
                        setText(null);
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        setOnDragEntered(event -> setTextFill(Color.DARKRED));
                        setOnDragExited(event -> setTextFill(Color.BLACK));

                        setOnDragOver(event -> {
                            if (event.getGestureSource() != this &&
                                    event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
                            }

                            event.consume();
                        });

                        setOnDragDropped(event ->
                        {
                            if (getItem() == null) {
                                return;
                            }

                            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
                            boolean success = false;
                            if (db.hasString()) {
                                int index = Integer.valueOf(db.getString());
                                XBeeNode node = nodeListView.getItems().get(index);
                                if (node != null) {
                                    if (!node.getZone().equals(getItem())) {
                                        String actual_zone = node.getZone();
                                        if (!changedNodes.containsKey(node)) {
                                            changedNodes.put(node, node.getZone());
                                            System.out.println(changedNodes.toString());
                                        }
                                        node.getZone();
                                        node.setZone(getItem());
                                        NodesFilteredList.setPredicate(data ->
                                        {
                                            if (actual_zone == null || actual_zone.isEmpty())
                                                return true;
                                            if (actual_zone.equals("*"))
                                                return true;
                                            else if ((data.getZone().equals(actual_zone) ))
                                                return true;
                                            else if (data.getZone().endsWith(actual_zone))
                                                return true;
                                            else return false;
                                        });
                                    }

                                }
                                success = true;
                            }
                            /* let the source know whether the string was successfully
                             * transferred and used */
                            event.setDropCompleted(success);

                            event.consume();
                        });

                        if (item.equals("*"))
                            setTextFill(Color.RED); // Here is where change the text color

                        setText(item == null ? "null" : item.toString());
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                }
            };
            cell.setOnDragDone(DragEvent::consume);

            return cell;
        })
```

So I have an init list items as follows:

1. *
2. A
3. Z00

At beginning only the first item ("*") has red text color. But as I said before, after add a new element, another cell change its color.

[Sample of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xizxY.png)

Comment: Do you reset the color if the cell is empty, the item is null, or the item doesn't fit the requirements? Remember, cell instances are _reused_.

Comment: @Slaw Wow I did what you said and now it works as I want. Thank you very much! Now how can I set your answer as the correct one?

Comment: If you want, you can answer your own question and show/explain the changes that fixed the problem. (_I didn't really answer your question, I just pointed you towards the probable issue. Hence the comment rather than an answer._)